# How to load a data file having lines ending with '|' in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to load a big file of data in postgres.
Fileds are delimited by '|' but my problem is that each line of my data file ends with '|' and '\n' . So postgres is expecting another field after the last '|'.
For small files I've just removed the last '|' and data were loaded correctly using `COPY`, but I have some files that exceed 800000 rows, what is the best way to proceed ?

#### Example of data files rows:

- 5|ETHIOPIA|0|ven packages wake quickly. regu|
- 6|FRANCE|3|refully final requests. regular, ironi|

Comment: Is it being entered direct into the final table? If not just add a column to the intermediate table.

Comment: Yes, I think this is a practical solution ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like `sed` to remove the last char of the file

```
cat file_with_80K_lines.txt | sed s'/.$//' > last_char_removed.txt
```